# How to track changes made in a Google Drive Folder (with a script)?

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to know how I can implement a trigger of sorts to track changes made in a Google Drive Folder. I looked at DriveApp documentation but couldn't find anything, then I came upon some posts about Google Drive Activity API. After that, I tried to look into the documentation of Drive Activity API but couldn't wrap my head around it. So, is it possible to do such a thing using Drive Activity API?

Comment: What exactly do you want to track? What information do you want to get when a file is added to the folder, for example? Or when a file is modified? Also, should this trigger fire at the moment the change is made, or it can run periodically?

Comment: Well, we have a drive folder that we use as an archive for course materials in our department. What I have at hand is a script that creates a content page for this drive folder. What I want is to be able to run this script whenever something is added or removed from the folder. In other words, I would like to trigger to fire at the moment of change (if it is possible)

Comment: You could [watch changes to your folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch) via [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push). That would send a notification to a webhook you registered, but I'm not sure whether you can use that to trigger your script: can you provide more details about your script?